# A* pathfinding algorithm - got stuck calculating shortest path

Tags: c#, algorithm, a-star

I'm trying to implement A* algorithm in order to find the shortest path in given grid.

My Node class:

```
public class Node : IComparable
    {
        public Node(int row, int col, Node previousNode = null, double distance = double.PositiveInfinity)
        {
            this.Row = row;
            this.Col = col;
            this.PreviousNode = previousNode;
            this.Distance = distance;
        }

        public int Row { get; }

        public int Col { get; }

        public bool IsVisited { get; internal set; }

        public double Distance { get; set; } 

        public int Weight { get; set; } = 1;

        public double GScore { get; set; } = double.PositiveInfinity;

        public double H { get; set; }

        public double FScore => this.GScore + this.H;

        public NodeType? NodeType { get; internal set; }

        public Node PreviousNode { get; set; }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            var otherNode = obj as Node;
            return this.Equals(otherNode);
        }

        protected bool Equals(Node other)
            => this.Row == other.Row && this.Col == other.Col;

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            unchecked
            {
                return (this.Row * 397) ^ this.Col;
            }
        }

        public int CompareTo(object obj)
        {
            var otherNode = obj as Node;
            if (this.FScore == otherNode.FScore)
            {
                if (this.H >= otherNode.H)
                {
                    return 1;
                }
                else if (this.H < otherNode.H)
                {
                    return -1;
                }
            }

            return this.FScore.CompareTo(otherNode.FScore);
        }
    }
```

A* algo class:

```
public override Result Execute(Node[,] grid, Node startNode, Node endNode)
        {
            var heap = new MinHeap<Node>();
            var allSteps = new HashSet<Node>();

            startNode.GScore = 0;
            startNode.H = ManhattanDistance(startNode, endNode);
            startNode.IsVisited = true;
            heap.Add(startNode);

            while (heap.Count != 0)
            {
                var currentNode = heap.Pop();

                if (currentNode.NodeType == NodeType.Wall)
                    continue;

                allSteps.Add(currentNode);

                if (currentNode.Equals(endNode))
                {
                    return new Result(allSteps, this.GetAllNodesInShortestPathOrder(currentNode));
                }

                var rowDirection = new[] { -1, +1, 0, 0 };
                var columnDirection = new[] { 0, 0, +1, -1 };
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                {
                    var currentRowDirection = currentNode.Row + rowDirection[i];
                    var currentColDirection = currentNode.Col + columnDirection[i];

                    if ((currentRowDirection < 0 || currentColDirection < 0)
                        || (currentRowDirection >= grid.GetLength(0)
                            || currentColDirection >= grid.GetLength(1)))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    var nextNode = grid[currentRowDirection, currentColDirection];
                    AddNodeToHeap(currentNode, nextNode, endNode, heap);
                }
            }

            return new Result(allSteps);
        }

        private void AddNodeToHeap(Node currentNode, Node nextNode, Node endNode, MinHeap<Node> heap)
        {
            if (nextNode.IsVisited || nextNode.GScore < currentNode.GScore)
                return;

            var g = currentNode.GScore + nextNode.Weight;
            var h = ManhattanDistance(nextNode, endNode);

            if (g + h < nextNode.FScore)
            {
                nextNode.GScore = g;
                nextNode.H = h;
                nextNode.PreviousNode = currentNode;
                nextNode.IsVisited = true;
            }

            heap.Add(nextNode);
        }

        private static int ManhattanDistance(Node currentNode, Node endNode)
        {
            var dx = Math.Abs(currentNode.Row - endNode.Row);
            var dy = Math.Abs(currentNode.Col - endNode.Col);
            return dx + dy;
        }
```

Custom MinHeap class:

```
public class MinHeap<T>
    {
        private readonly IComparer<T> comparer;
        private readonly List<T> list = new List<T> { default };

        public MinHeap() 
            : this(default(IComparer<T>))
        {
        }

        public MinHeap(IComparer<T> comparer)
        {
            this.comparer = comparer ?? Comparer<T>.Default;
        }

        public MinHeap(Comparison<T> comparison) 
            : this(Comparer<T>.Create(comparison))
        {
        }

        public int Count => this.list.Count - 1;

        public void Add(T element)
        {
            this.list.Add(element);
            this.ShiftUp(this.list.Count - 1);
        }

        public T Pop()
        {
            T result = this.list[1];
            this.list[1] = this.list[^1];
            this.list.RemoveAt(this.list.Count - 1);
            this.ShiftDown(1);
            return result;
        }

        private static int Parent(int i) => i / 2;
        private static int Left(int i) => i * 2;
        private static int Right(int i) => i * 2 + 1;

        private void ShiftUp(int i)
        {
            while (i > 1)
            {
                int parent = Parent(i);
                if (this.comparer.Compare(this.list[i], this.list[parent]) > 0)
                {
                    return;
                }

                (this.list[parent], this.list[i]) = (this.list[i], this.list[parent]);
                i = parent;
            }
        }

        private void ShiftDown(int i)
        {
            for (int left = Left(i); left < this.list.Count; left = Left(i))
            {
                int smallest = this.comparer.Compare(this.list[left], this.list[i]) <= 0 ? left : i;
                int right = Right(i);
                if (right < this.list.Count && this.comparer.Compare(this.list[right], this.list[smallest]) <= 0)
                {
                    smallest = right;
                }

                if (smallest == i)
                {
                    return;
                }

                (this.list[i], this.list[smallest]) = (this.list[smallest], this.list[i]);
                i = smallest;
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that it doesn't find the optimal path when I have some weights on the map. For example:
Every square on the grid which is marked as a weight node has weight of 10 otherwise it's 1.
Here's example:

[Example grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7dJ8.png) with 3 weight nodes - green node is start node, red node is end node and the dumbbell node is weight node.

When I run the algorithm I get the following [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70Bdy.jpg).
It's clearly visible that this is not the shortest path since the algorithm goes through the first node which has weight 1 and then the next node with weight 10 instead of just passing one 10 weight node. The shortest path should've been the red one which I've marked.

P.S I've managed to make it respect the weights by adding new heuristic function when calculating GCost and it now calculates the path but instead of one straight line I get some strange path: [image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't think you code can work as is.  Each Node can have up to 8 neighbors (outside rows have less).  So you need an array of neighbors so you can give a different weight to each neighbor.

Comment: @jdweng I can move in only four directions - up,down, right, left. It's the same as Dijkstra algo but I can't make it work... with this heuristic method

Comment: What is the weight of your path compared to the one that the program got?  Calculate by hand.  There may be more than one solution.

Comment: @jdweng The problem is that in my MinHeap I pop the Node with the lowest FScore and on the first iteration I get lower Fscore for the row 1 column 0 than the row 0 column 1 since the weight is higher but it doesn't take in count that on the next iteration I have again weight node and then the total distance is normal node + 1 weight node instead of 1 weight node. Hope that helps you

Comment: You need to have a cumulative weight and not just the weight for each node.  Which also means you have to test every path.  So you need to save best path.  And when you reach  end you continue because there may be another path that is better.

Comment: @jdweng but then would that even be A* ? I think it's Dijkstra then

Comment: Maybe.  Dijkstra says path and doesn't restrict to just one.  Because of weight, you could have 10 steps with a weight of 100 and 11 steps with weight of 99.  So reaching end doesn't mean you stop even with no weights.  You can have three different types of Dijkstra 1) Any path 2) Minimum path no weights 3) Minimum path with weights.

Comment: A-Star should go to the point almost right away. It's an informed search it should go left then down in one go. If there is no obstacle.

Comment: @xdtTransform Read my answer down below, I think I made it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jdweng

I actually fixed the bug by implementing an additional method which adds additional weight to the GScore

blue squares - all steps which the algorithm took in order to find the shortest final path

A* Algo with weights
 [image: A* algo]

A* algo without weights
[[image]

Dijkstra Algo with weights
[image]

Dijkstra Algo without weights
[image]

```
private (double weight, NodeDirection? Direction) GetDistanceAndDirection(Node nodeOne, Node nodeTwo)
        {
            var x1 = nodeOne.Row;
            var y1 = nodeOne.Col;
            var x2 = nodeTwo.Row;
            var y2 = nodeTwo.Col;

            if (x2 < x1 && y1 == y2)
            {
                switch (nodeOne.Direction)
                {
                    case NodeDirection.Up:
                        return (1, NodeDirection.Up);
                    case NodeDirection.Right:
                        return (2, NodeDirection.Up);
                    case NodeDirection.Left:
                        return (2, NodeDirection.Up);
                    case NodeDirection.Down:
                        return (3, NodeDirection.Up);
                }
            }
            else if (x2 > x1 && y1 == y2)
            {
                switch (nodeOne.Direction)
                {
                    case NodeDirection.Up:
                        return (3, NodeDirection.Down);
                    case NodeDirection.Right:
                        return (2, NodeDirection.Down);
                    case NodeDirection.Left:
                        return (2, NodeDirection.Down);
                    case NodeDirection.Down:
                        return (1, NodeDirection.Down);
                }
            }
            if (y2 < y1 && x1 == x2)
            {
                switch (nodeOne.Direction)
                {
                    case NodeDirection.Up:
                        return (2, NodeDirection.Left);
                    case NodeDirection.Right:
                        return (3, NodeDirection.Left);
                    case NodeDirection.Left:
                        return (1, NodeDirection.Left);
                    case NodeDirection.Down:
                        return (2, NodeDirection.Left);
                }
            }
            else if (y2 > y1 && x1 == x2)
            {
                switch (nodeOne.Direction)
                {
                    case NodeDirection.Up:
                        return (2, NodeDirection.Right);
                    case NodeDirection.Right:
                        return (1, NodeDirection.Right);
                    case NodeDirection.Left:
                        return (3, NodeDirection.Right);
                    case NodeDirection.Down:
                        return (2, NodeDirection.Right);
                }
            }

            return default;
        }
```

and then AddNodeToHeapMethod()

```
private void AddNodeToHeap(Node currentNode, Node nextNode, Node endNode, MinHeap<Node> heap)
        {
            if (nextNode.IsVisited)
                return;

            var (additionalWeight, direction) = this.GetDistanceAndDirection(currentNode, nextNode);
            var g = currentNode.GScore+ nextNode.Weight + additionalWeight;
            var h = this.ManhattanDistance(nextNode, endNode);

            if (g < nextNode.GScore)
            {

                nextNode.GScore= g;
                nextNode.H = h;
                nextNode.PreviousNode = currentNode;
                nextNode.IsVisited = true;
            }

            currentNode.Direction = direction;

            heap.Add(nextNode);
        }
```